# SFC Couldn't Perform Requested Operation -- Options?

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt, operating-system

I had a user come to me with her company issued Dell laptop. After the "Dell" splash screen is done, Windows does not boot. It's just a blank, black screen. After rebooting several times via the power button (as usual methods weren't available) I managed to get the Windows recovery screen to come up. I opened a Command Prompt, and ran `sfc /scannow`, but it came up as not being able to perform the requested operation. No further information was given. I tried it again, to the same result. Then I ran `sfc /verifyonly`, and it did find integrity violations. Reinstalling Windows isn't preferred as the user is in Billing and the laptop has things that she needs. I have her laptop, while she works on a desktop. My question is, what're my options? I have a thought, but I don't know if such a solution exists:

Take NVME out of laptop,
plug it in to my machine via USB (I have an adapter),
and *somehow* run a Command Prompt against the NVME to see if sfc can work this time.

The user had mentioned she closed the laptop before it happened, so maybe it's a sleep related issue. Are there any software solutions out there that allow Windows to be run in a container on an external drive, or something similar that would allow me to repair Windows without reinstalling it?

Thanks for everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: no options. I ended up reinstalling.